# How to get enum values in capitalization

Tags: java, enums

We create Enum classes and write all enum members in Full Uppercase.

```
public enum Color {
    RED,
    YELLOW,
    BLACK
}
```

How can we get the values in Capitalization (Writing the first letter of a word in uppercase, and the rest of the letters in lowercase) in java.

Meaning, when I fetch the Value of `Color` Enum, I should get as `Red`, `Yellow`, `Black`

Comment: [https://www.baeldung.com/java-enum-values] - adding useful link for reference.

all answers were correct with different approaches.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use [java enums name() method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#name()), you have no choice but to write the values in Capitalization in your code.

If you want to get a «display name» for each color, you can add a String field to your enum, like in the example below:

```
public enum Color {
    RED("Red"),
    YELLOW("Yellow"),
    BLACK("Black");

    String displayName;

    Color(String displayName){
         this.displayName = displayName;
    }
}
```

Then you can access the capitalized name with `RED.displayName` for example.

Last solution, you can manually capitalize the name, with the code below:

```
String str = RED.name();
String displayName = str.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + str.substring(1).toLowerCase();
```

Comment: Good Answer. I would mark that `displayName` as `final` to prevent inadvertent change.

Answer (score 1):

An enum can be more than just the simple constant as you have it in your snippet. Check out https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html, especially the planet example.

So of course you can override the toString() method and whatever else you need to get your representation running.

Comment: Okay. If I use like Planet Example. when I try to set the same in Database, it gets stored in String (which is basically the capitalized value that I'm declaring while creating enum).
However, while fetching the same from DB, it may throw error about the type mismatch.

Answer (score 1):

If you're able to use Apache StringUtils, you could first use [`String.toLowerCase()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toLowerCase()), and then [`StringUtils.capitalize()`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#capitalize-java.lang.String-), converting for example "RED" to "red" to "Red".

Here's your original enum declaration:

```
public enum Color {
    RED,
    YELLOW,
    BLACK
}
```

And here's an example that:

- iterates each enum value
- prints the name by calling `name()`
- calls `toLowerCase()`, and prints that value
- calls `capitalize()` with the lowercase value, and prints that, too
- one final `println()` so the output isn't all bunched up

```
for (Color value : Color.values()) {
    String name = value.name();
    System.out.println("       name: " + name);
    
    String lowerCased = name.toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(" lowerCased: " + lowerCased);
    
    String capitalized = StringUtils.capitalize(lowerCased);
    System.out.println("capitalized: " + capitalized);
    
    System.out.println();
}
```

Here is the output from that code:

```
       name: RED
 lowerCased: red
capitalized: Red

       name: YELLOW
 lowerCased: yellow
capitalized: Yellow

       name: BLACK
 lowerCased: black
capitalized: Black
```

This shows how to do the conversion, leaving the enum definitions are they are (uppercase; "RED", etc).

If you'd like to incorporate this into the enum definition itself, you could do something like this:

```
public enum Color {
    RED,
    YELLOW,
    BLACK;

    public final String getDisplayName() {
        return StringUtils.capitalize(this.name().toLowerCase());
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
for (Color value : Color.values()) {
    System.out.println(value.getDisplayName());
}
```

Which would produce output like this:

```
Red
Yellow
Black
```